# Hidden permalink different from displayed permalink

Tags: plugins, custom-post-types, permalinks, url-rewriting, redirect

I am working on a website which I did not create on WordPress for a company and I am running into the following issue.

### Structure

- Category: `fruits`
- Sub-categories: `red`, `yellow`, `orange`
- Items: `apples`, `oranges`, `lemons`

When `apples` are selected the permalink would be: `food.com/fruits/red/apples/`. In this example, there are pages dedicated to each of the following:

- food.com/fruits/
- food.com/fruits/red/
- food.com/fruits/red/apples/

### Problem

When you navigate to one of the sub-categories (such as `red`), the page shows the content of the items (`apples`) instead of the sub-category page itself.

Ex: `fruits` -> `red` is selected.

- Page showing: food.com/fruits/red/**apples**/ (1)
- Permalink showing: food.com/fruits/red/ (2)
- If I **don't** select a sub-category on the page builder (`apples` does not have a colour selected) and navigate:

  - food.com/fruits/**red**/ -> apples -> food.com/fruits/**colour**/apples/
  - in this case the `red` page displays, but the permalink is missing the `colour` category even though you would navigate through `red` to get to `apples`.

If there are multiple items in the sub-category, it displays an item at random. It could be the first item, it could be the third item, however it will be consistent where it displays the same item *every time*.

I have searched through every plugin `.php` file and so far have not been able to find anything useful. What I *was* able to do however, was print out the hidden permalink, which looks like (1), even though the browser link displays (2).

### Question

How do I select a sub-category for each item and still display the sub-category page? Each sub-category page is built and set up, but right now I can't view any of them on the site without removing the sub-category selections from each item.

[image]

Comment: but does the red category not contain the apples category? Parent child relationships with terms are nested, think of them not as connected boxes, but nested boxes. The fruit category doesn't just contain everything you checked the fruit box, it contains everything where you checked the sub-terms/children too. I'm assuming that fruit/red/apple are all terms in a single taxonomy, with their primary difference being how deep down the hierarchy they are?

Comment: Red does contain apples, but when I'm editing the site and I say that apples is in the "red box", then when I navigate to red on the website it shows the apples page instead of the red page. Also yes, the fruits/red/apple section is made up of hierarchical sections where users can navigate to fruits, then to red, then to apples, with a different page at each step.

Comment: red contains apples, so all things in the apples term will also appear in red. It sounds like you want only items marked as red, but not reds children to be displayed, which is not standard behaviour, is that correct?

Comment: Sorry, I think we're getting some wired crossed. Red contains apples, however red has its own page with information on red itself. It has a section with links to navigate to see the apples information, with a 200 character preview/description of what is contained in apples.  The apples page is independent of the red page. Keep in mind that red may also contain cherries, strawberries, and raspberries, which will each have a button with a small description right alongside apples.

Comment: Think of it like a textbook. Fruits is a section of the book which contains all colour categories and all fruits within them. The colour categories have brief descriptions of all of the fruits with a page number to jump to that specific fruit. The fruit itself contains in depth information about that specific fruit. I hope this helps :)

Comment: No I think that just adds confusion, I don't know how to relate it to your question to figure out what you want. Can you un-genericise it so that we can use the actual problem to solve the question? By hiding things you've made it much harder not easier to understand, the analogy seems to be confusing things not clearing them up, it is not clear/specific what the problem is

Comment: What's more I think you've left out critical information. I suspect that when you say the content, you are not referring to the posts from that term, but are referring to a page you have not disclosed, and that you're actually using pages with page templates that have content, and this is what is incorrect. However if that was the case you would have mentioned it, and you did not. When you say page, do you mean a web page, or a literal post of type `page`?

Comment: Also I'm just seeing now that you mentioned a page builder, what is this page builder? Have you asked via their support? Are you using the page builder to display the pages content and the posts listed? What is an item? A term? A page? Or is it some component of the page builder? There's a high chance that the solution to your problem will only work for the specific page builder you have chosen, but I cannot tell with the limited information available

Comment: Hmm ok sorry about that, I will go back to your previous comment. I want to display small descriptions of red's children on the red page, and make those descriptions link to a child page. Right now the red page is displaying one of the children's pages, yet showing the permalink for the red page. In this scenario, you can't see red's other children because the wrong page is being displayed in the first place. I will add an image to my post to hopefully help, sorry for all of the confusion!

Comment: They are of type `post`. This website was made by another company who created a custom theme, however that company is no longer available to contact for support. I am using the page builder to display both the content of the page AND the listed posts. An item is a page.

Comment: I understand if it's a problem with the custom site and I really appreciate all the help you have offered so far. Thank you for your patience with me I am new to this.